# Android programming ,Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token

Tags: java, android

i am beginner in android programming . i tried to add a text view or anything in my app. but 
somehow in id class which is automatically generated in r.java , i am getting invalid character as u can see in textview and i can't delete it or alter it . need help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
  public static final class id {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f080001;
    public static final int textViewà¥§=0x7f080000;
}
```

Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it yourself. This:

```
textViewà¥§
```

Is not an acceptable name.

This one is:

```
textView1
```

This one also is:

```
txtSomething
```

Delete R.java and change the name in your xml layout.

**Yes, you can**

Comment: You see... it was so easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

`§` character is not allowed in variable names, simply remove it from your variable `textViewà¥§` to correct the error.

The generated code file may be read-only, so change the file property to make it editable. If you don't have the source file, then you may try to edit the class file using [classeditor](http://classeditor.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
1. Delete R.java
2. uncheck Preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown->Android Development Toolkit
3. check it back and restart eclipse, then R will generate automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an error saying that I had an invalid token on my `R.java` and indeed a string had an `'` at the variable name, which is not permitted of course, but that string was not made by me but by the system so i could not fix it manually !

What I did was cleaning and building not only the current project but also the support library that I used for that project. Doing so the error popped up on the library project also !

Since I could not fix it manually, **I deleted the support library and reimported a new support library which solved my problem**.